# What's a better way of saying "doing something for fun"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, phrases

I am writing a discussion summary for my class and one of the questions I have to answer is if I would recommend the personality test we had to take. I want to say I would recommend it for fun or as a joke. But I know that there are other ways to make it sound more scholarly.

Comment: Do it, "for science!" or simply "for the lulz"

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend it, but *purely for entertainment value*.

> 'It is neat to see they include words purely for entertainment value
>   (failing to meet all other criteria for inclusion.)' [[Wiktionary_talk](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary_talk:Copyrights)]